# Need help interpreting this rails asset file extension: .js.jst.jsthtml.haml

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-3

I've inherited a Ruby on Rails & AngularJS web app. Some of the static assets have the file extension`.js.jst.jsthtml.haml`, and I'm trying to unpack what each part of the extension means:

- `.haml` is the rails HAML template [processor](http://haml.info/tutorial.html)
- `.jsthtml` is ???
- `.jst` is the rails [javascript template precompiler](http://www.bigjason.com/blog/precompiled-javascript-templates-rails-3-1)?
- `.js` is used to indicate that the resulting file is a *javascript* template

Can someone help me flesh this out, especially what the `.jsthtml` extension is for?

Comment: `jsthtml`  = A JST template that renders html?  Ugh, who the hell uses a tool which can't bother to have an english readme? especially when there are a crazy amount of alternatives?

Comment: @max if you can point me to the docs for JST templates, where I might be able to read more about HTML JST templates, I'd sure appreciate it! I tried googling, but didn't turn up much.

Comment: I am not going much further than html.erb or js.erb but "foobar" does not sound like Something really production oriented. It may be an unused remainder. Have you check the controller to see if this is called somewhere ?..

Comment: Sorry, the base filename is _not_ `foobar`, it's something else that's business-specific and not really relevant to the question. I'll remove "foobar" from the heading so it doesn't cause any further confusion!